# Grails not loading classes in .jar file

Tags: grails, groovy, jar

I am interested in using a certain library ([Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki), the graph traversal language) in my Grails project. I dropped the necessary .jars into [grailsproject]/lib. But when I do `grails run-app` it gives me a compilation error re:a class 'Gremlin' which is part of the jar (I confirmed that it is included in the jar by running `tar tf <jarfile>.jar`, and it shows the class Gremlin):

```
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed,
...unexpected token: Gremlin @ line 45, column 2.
  [groovyc]     Gremlin.load()
  [groovyc]     ^
```

Is there a way to "refresh" Grails to make sure it loads the new jar files? I use the exact same jar in an independent groovy test app with the same import statements, and there I am able to use the Gremlin class and it works fine. My system $CLASSPATH doesn't include any jar files that I haven't also added in [grailsproject]/lib.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Update**: Here's the relevant section from the code:

```
package com.mycompany.myproject

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH
import com.orientechnologies.common.collection.*
import com.orientechnologies.common.*
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.*
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.*
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.*
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.impls.orientdb.*
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.*
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Gremlin
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.*


class GraphDbService {

    boolean transactional = true    

    Gremlin.load()

    ...
```

Comment: Can you post the source for the class that causes the errors?  Or just the relevant section? I assume you `import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Gremlin`?

Comment: I added the code, and yes, I do import Gremlin as well as gremlin.* for good measure

Comment: what version of grails are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to put `Gremlin.load()` inside a method, not just in the definition section of your service class...

ie:

```
class GraphDbService {
  boolean transactional = true    

  def someServiceMethod() {
    Gremlin.load()
  }

  ...
```

Or, preferably, you should be able to put it in the `init()` method of your `BootStrap.groovy` file, as it only needs calling once , so that it can decorate all of the required classes.

Comment: Thanks Tim! +1 for the pointer on putting it in the BootStrap.groovy file, and that's the solution that I've implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to add the following to the `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    //...bunch of stuff
    dependencies {
        // other resolved dependencies here

        compile files('lib/gremlim.jar')
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work.. it outputs the message `WARNING: Configurational method [runtime] in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy doesn't exist. Ignoring..
` when I run `grails run-app` and then gives the same compilation error as before.

Comment: BuildConfig doesn't exist!... looking at your update you might just need to add static { } around the Gremlim load .. you currently have it defined in the middle of a class

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```